# How to deploy spring-boot application to nexus without include all the spring-boot libraries?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jar, nexus

i am looking for an ability to deploy an spring-boot application as an artefact in nexus (our company maven repository). The application runs itself very well and i wouldn't like to refactory it as a standard spring application.

The issue is the following. By execution the `~> maven deploy`,  the `maven` deploys the `target/transformation.excel.input-XXX.RELEASE.jar` archive very nice. But:

1. the deploying `jar` is very heavyweight
2. the `jar` contains the classes of projects in `BOOT-INF/classes/com/ ...` folder. You can see it here:

[image]

It is sure very well to start this boot-application from terminal, but in my case it is inadmissible.

And most important is

3. Because of actual structure of `jar`-archive, the third project (which has the dependency to this `transformation.input.excel`-artefact) can't see source classes and compiler shows the error.

I believe there is some opportunities to make the spring-boot artefact more comfortable for `nexus(maven)`-repository. Perhaps  there could be a jar-plugin solution, but i don't have any experience to do it.

i would be very thankful for assist/help how it can be solved. So, some time i have to to run this application from terminal and sometime the application can be used as functionality-provider

sorry for my English

regards

Comment: So in a way, your question is not really about nexus but rather how to split spring boot's jar into "YourApp-withoutspringbootlibs.jar" + "springbootlibraries.jar" ? Then, you'd only deploy YourApp-withoutspringbootlibs.jar ?

Comment: Practically you have right. Yes, i need the jar with source code without spring-boot libraries. By executing the mnv package, maven create two files in the target folder. The first one is realy spring-boot jar with all dependencies and where my source is not reachably because of structure. The second one is a XXX.jar.original that contains only the source code without any dependencies.

Comment: I would like to have the second one, but i don't know how to force maven find the dependencies by itself. I just tested it and compiler is happy. But by running the application there is the runtime exception. Somethink like: "can't find the third party library"

Comment: One issure in that case, i can't execute directly [mvn deploy]. I have to delete the first jar-file,  then rename the second file (xxxx.jar.original -> xxx.jar) and then deploy by hand. Finally, by deploying this way the compiler is happy but without any dependencies l recieve the exception by executin the application.

Comment: You are mixing 2 problems at once. I suggest you to rephrase your question into something like "Spring Boot: How to build runnable jar with spring-libraries in a separate jar". And until you make this work, you should put nexus aside.. Once you have 2 working jars, then you can find the best way to deploy them in nexus.

Answer (score 3):

the solution is here:

```js
     <plugins>

  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
    <classifier>exec</classifier>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
```